# How to simplify drawing a geometry

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is there a function or script that allows you to soften a geometry (a kind of inscribed smoothing that follows the contour of the geometry)

[image]

at the moment, I don't have much of an idea (a priori a buffer doesn't work, the minimum oriented footprints are rectangular, the convex envelopes are too big)...

Comment: Is this about symbology, or the actual geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [QGIS simplify tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissimplifygeometries)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`native:smoothgeometry`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#smooth) algorithm in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

I finish with WhiteBox Tools / smoothVectors
[image]